# import css error file path incorrect?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to import the following css file into my base.html file:

```
STglobalStyles.css
```

my folder structure is as follows:

```
suitsandtables
    static
       css
         STglobalStyles.css
    templates
        base.html
```

I am trying to affect the color of text in my base in a span

STglobalStyles.css content is the following:

```
.STBlue{
    color: #0dc3ff;
}
```

it is linked in base.html as the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="suitsandtables/static/css/STglobalStyles.css" type="text/css">
```

(note I am prototyping this is not how I will actually import in production)

here is the html in question:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase" href="#">Suits <span class="STBlue">+ </span> Tables</a>
```

what am I doing wrong as the style IS coming though, but the + should be the blue I want, and such isn't.

The file is not rendering at all.

Thank you, hugs and kisses.

Comment: @Tiramonium hey man, sorry the file IS coming through, just tested it again. the + is not the blue I want

Comment: If you're using simple html in your tags and not some server language, use `../` instead of the folder name, that way html will know to look for a file a folder up one level above the current directory. Something like `href="../../css/STglobalStyles.css"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the link as below

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/../STglobalStyles.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: thank you, I have a new problem now. The css file is now properly linked, however my color style is not coming through

Comment: So, now your stylesheet i.e css is getting rendered right ?

Comment: correct, just the specific style I am trying to do is not being applied. I tested that the file is indeed being rendered by placing text next to the + and applying `text-transform: uppercase;` to it.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you want to achieve on the text Suites+Tables ?

Comment: sure.  here is the html code  `<a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase" href="#">Suits <span class="STBlue"> + </span> Tables</a>`   now I am trying to make the "+" blue within the span. Hence the span has a class of "STBlue" the class "STBlue" has the following within it: `color: #0dc3ff;`

Comment: so you want to make the + in blue color (#0dc3ff) right ?

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work for you, because it works perfectly fine here with me! First try putting your CSS and HTML in same page and run it once

Comment: If your css and html is placed on the same page and the code works, which in your case should definitely work, then the problem is in your stylesheet rendering ! Try using absolute path on the other hand and check it

Comment: I have tried absolute rendering, or at least what I think is absolute that being `/211hospitality/suitsandtables/static/css/STglobalStyles.css` to which still nothing. I have switched from sublime text to webstorm and still noting this is amazing, I truly have no idea why this isn't working..

Comment: Did u try pasting the css and html on the same page.Try doing that and running it once ! Please

Comment: So the only problem is here <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" " />, copy this and paste it and just edit the href part and try.Carefully notice the / in the ending.

Comment: interesting, you have a closing link tag.. the CSS i have coming in by CDN does not. The link tag on CDNs closes as such >

Comment: Yes, there is a closing tag ! Which I realized when I cross checked your code. So finally it works right ?

Comment: lol, sooo. this didn't work either. Im getting ready to go on the street and be like hi , do you know html css? this is amazing. thank you for helping me still though man

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/211hospitality/suitsandtables/static/css/STglobalStyles.css" /> also does not work ?

Comment: so im starting to think this is an issue with bootstrap I had webstorm generate the absolute and relative paths to the css and still nothing

Comment: Probably yes because these are the maximum css and html validations as far as I know.